# Плавный слайдинг картинок в галерее

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Как известно по умолчанию стандартный контрол Gallery слайдит изображения рывками. Как сделать чтобы он слайдил плавно или с какой-то задержкой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо указать соответствующее значение **android:animationDuration** в файле xml разметки или **setAnimationDuration(int)** в коде.